# How to Change Language of Windows 10 Single Language Without Format

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

I'm working on a computer which has **Windows 10 Home Single Language**.

The language cannot normally be changed on Settings since its Single Language version.

So how do I change the interface language for Windows **without reinstalling** Windows?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Okay this is how I handle this situation.
First you should setup the language pack of the desired language to use.

1. If you haven't done already, download your desired language pack. This usually can be done from Windows 10 Settings > Time & Language > Language tab and then clicking on Add language.
2. Check the language packs on your computer to confirm it was installed. Press `Win+R` and type `cmd`, then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to open Command Prompt with Administrator rights.
3. Type `dism /online /get-packages` and press `Enter`. 
   We are looking for **Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package** as a start for **Package Identity**. And its **State** should be **Installed**
   [Check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoP0c.png)
   You can see next 5 characters after **~** for understand which language it is. In this example, we are seeing **tr-TR**. If you are looking for English for example, you should look for **en-US**.
4. **If you found the desired language in the step above, skip this step.** Otherwise, continue reading.
   You will have to manually download and install the language pack you want. To do that, go to this [link](https://www.appsforwin10.com/windows-10-1909-iso-19h2/) for Windows 10 1909 (UPDATE: Go to this [link](https://appsforwin10.com/windows-10-2004-iso-20h1-language-pack/) for Windows 10 2004). Then select language pack you want to download. Then go to Command Prompt (Admin rights) again and type `Dism /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\lp.cab`. **Don't forget to change** `PackagePath` to your downloaded **.cab file's path** before you type! Then press `Enter` to install downloaded language pack
5. Press `Win+R` and type `regedit`, then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to open Regedit with Administrator rights. Then go to `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language`

   **Default** entry shows that language id of your system. Check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to look your desired language id from list. Copy the part after **0x** part. For example for **en-US**, get **0409** [Check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idMMr.png)
6. Double click to **Default** (In some cases you might need to change **InstallLanguage**'s id as well) to edit this entry and paste the language id you copied. Save and restart your computer.

Comment: Heads up: This is a dangerous operation, may lead to potential system failure. If it unfortunately happends to you as well, try running `regedit` in the cmd of Windows Recovery, then load Hive `c:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM` and revert back your changes.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: What about Windows 11? Is it more or less the same procedure? Thanks.

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov Yes, it does work on Windows 11! _Windows 11 Home Single Language, Version 21H2_, to be precise, and I had to change both **Default** and **InstallLanguage** registry entries to **0409** for it to be successful.

Comment: @tatoline Please don't screenshot terminal output, instead please copy/paste it into code box, and when attaching screenshots, please inline them by either using the Media toolbar button or by prefacing the link with an `!`

Comment: @ArionKrause I don't believe `en-US` [`0409`] counts, as it's the default language in all Windows editions as a fallback language _(all Windows OS programming is `en-US`, which is why, for example, the Registry doesn't change when set to other languages)_

Answer (score 9):

While the accepted answer can work, it's also possible that the .cab file listed in those links doesn't work for your version of Win10. If that happens, you can find the language pack for your version by:

1. Visiting https://uupdump.ml/
2. Searching for keywords of your Win10 build. For example, System Information showed my Win10 was at version 10.0.18363, build 18363, so I entered "18363 amd64"
3. Clicking on a Cumulative update of your build in the search results
4. In Search files, search for "languagepack"
5. Downloading the .esd file of the language pack you wish to use
6. Converting the .esd file into a .cab file. You can use this tool for example https://github.com/abbodi1406/WHD/blob/master/scripts/ESD2CAB-CAB2ESD.zip . It has a readme explaining how to use it
7. Then following steps 4, 5 and 6 of the accepted answer

It might be a bit longer, but it's what I ended up doing since the .cab files listed there were not compatible with my build

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I did this with my newly bought Windows 10 home single language edition es-mx yesterday and managed to set it to english that way. That's how I came upon this post

Comment: It seems to be that the link in point 1 (https://uupdump.ml/) is really messed up.

Comment: there is also uupdump.net and uupdump.cn for mirror, just in case