# Alt + D in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is not working in the file explorer. I have a personal windows license. Is it possible to open this shortcut? Or I just basically have to use <kbd>F4</kbd>, which do the job but have disadvantages.

By the way, I am using Turkish Keyboard Layout.

Comment: Which Alt are you using and what's your keyboard layout?

Comment: It is not working for both Alt and Alt G. I am using Turkish keyboard layout.

Comment: Has it worked in the past?

Comment: no! It did no work.

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my own question because I found a solution for this problem. Basically, I change the language of Windows. It works!

However, If you are using Windows 10 Single Language, you can do the steps described by the user "Tatoline", and after setting your default language as English, this will do the job. This is not the complete solution of the problem but at least it works.

[Click Here In Order To Solve Single Language Problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1537466/how-to-change-language-of-windows-10-single-language-without-format)

I hope this works for others and help someone who encounters this particular issue.