# How to Change Language of Windows 11 Single Language Without Format

Tags: windows-11

[This question has been asked before for Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1537466/how-to-change-language-of-windows-10-single-language-without-format), however, the solution provided for Windows 10 does not appear to be working for Windows 11.

The problem is simple. I bought a new Laptop in Thailand. It came with Windows 11 Home Single Language Edition. 21H2. 22000.708. It is installed with English US (en-US, 0409). When I tried the procedure as described for Windows 10 and changed the language from English-US (en-US, 0809) to English-UK (en-UK, 0409) and restarted my laptop the display language had changed from English-US (en-US, 0809) to Thai (th-TH, 041E).

Does someone know of a solution for Windows 11 or is it possible that it is not possible to change the language to English-UK, and that it can only be changed from Thai to English-US and Vice Versa?

Comment: The language identification code for the languages you mentioned are identical between Windows 10 and Windows 11. I would repeat the process from scratch. My advice just accept the simplest solution would be to upgrade to Windows 11 Professional

Comment: While upgrading to multilingual/Pro is the only supported way from Microsoft, it would be odd for `Dism` and core Registry keys on Windows 10 to not work on Windows 11 - were all the steps in the linked to answer correctly executed? Were any error messages encountered? If upgrading to Pro, a format shouldn't be necessary, however, I would export all Registry hives `HKCR, `HKLM`, and `HKCC` via `Reg Export HKCR $env:UserProfile\HKCR.reg` _(etc.)_ prior to doing the following once the `install.<esd||wim>` is downloaded: _(cont'd...)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ Boot to WinPE/WinRE to directly apply the ESD/WIM index to the OS partition: Get index [image] for your version of Windows via `Dism /Get-ImageInfo` → Apply that index to the OS partition via `Dism /Apply-Image` → `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD` → Reboot. That method may not work, as I've never applied one version over another; if not, boot back to WinPE/WinRE and delete everything within the OS partition's `.\Windows` directory, then apply the ESD/WIM. You'll likely need to transfer over _specific_ Regsitry keys for certain programs from the previously exported hives

Comment: @JW0914. I never received an error message. After entering en-UK into the registry I restarted the laptop. When restarted it showed up in Thai and when I checked the registry it was changed to Thai (th-TH).

Comment: @JoeyJoystick the reversion implies there's another step that will need to be involved. In case it applies, many employers with Microsoft contracts _(incl. government/military)_ have Home Use Programs that allow you to purchase Windows Pro _(often ~$10)_ and Office at steep discounts.

Comment: @JW0914. I completely agree that I should use Windows 11 Pro. This is actually the first time in my life that I did not buy a pro version. Regret it already. Unfortunately, the upgrade scheme you're mentioning does not apply to me. But when I read it was working for Windows 10, I figured I should give it a shot for Windows 11.  And, no offense, but I hope this topic will be responded on at some time if there is a viable solution (and legal...). And in the meantime I will be looking for an upgrade. Pretty sure by now that there will be other things about Pro that I am gonna miss.

Comment: You confused the codes. `en-US = 0409`...

Answer (score 1):

for those seeking to switch to `en-us`, i've been able to do it without downloading anything, as it seems preinstalled.
in powershell:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language /v InstallLanguage /t REG_SZ /d 0409 /f
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language /v Default /t REG_SZ /d 1033 /f
```

then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The code for en-UK is 0809, not 0409. Try changing both Default and InstallLanguage to this number.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur's answer worked for me, just had to change %TEMP% in given commands to full path to Temp folder like this:

```
curl -o C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_en-gb.cab "https://filedn.com/lOX1R8Sv7vhpEG9Q77kMbn0/Windows11/LanguagePacks/Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_en-gb.cab"
dism /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_en-gb.cab
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language /v InstallLanguage /t REG_SZ /d 0809 /f
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language /v Default /t REG_SZ /d 2057 /f
cd
```

Be sure to run the command in administrator mode

Answer (score -1):

This website just helped me out to change from Portuguese-BR to English-US: https://leoguides.com/how-to-add-or-change-language-of-windows-11-home-single-language/

In case the website ever stops working, here are the cmd prompt instructions it gives for English-UK:

```
curl -o %TEMP%\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_en-gb.cab "https://filedn.com/lOX1R8Sv7vhpEG9Q77kMbn0/Windows11/LanguagePacks/Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_en-gb.cab"
dism /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:%TEMP%\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Language-Pack_x64_en-gb.cab
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language /v InstallLanguage /t REG_SZ /d 0809 /f
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language /v Default /t REG_SZ /d 2057 /f
```

Comment: I don't understand why vote down this answer. This is not work for me but it worked for Arthur, and may be for other people. But he did well answer, he even backed up for the case  the page is down.

Comment: The website redirects to a malicious ads. Honestly my downvote had nothing to do with that, it was the fact, there was no explanation, and of course this answer will stop working when the .can (which isn’t from Microsoft) link stops working